# How can I disable certificate?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I need to disable certificate to run some test, or someway to overpass it. What I want to archieve is that I have a list of data for each month with a field of date that I intend to trigger some job when current time reach to that date. I want to test it on previous month by changing my system date backward and that's when the error occur.

My orginal code

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
      {
 This is where the error happen---> result = await client.SendAsync(request);
        sent = sent && result.IsSuccessStatusCode;
      }
```

I have try changing it into this but still failed.

```
using (var httpCLientHandler = new HttpClientHandler())
      {
        httpCLientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (HttpRequestMessage, X509Certificate2, X509Chain, SslPolicyErrors) => { return true; };
        using (var client = new HttpClient(httpCLientHandler))
        {
          result = await client.SendAsync(request);
          sent = sent && result.IsSuccessStatusCode;
        }
      }
```

My error log

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details which can be done with a [mre]. Please [edit] your question to add these details into it or we may not be able to help.

Comment: What OS are you running this on?

Comment: I have update my error log. Sorry for the inconvinien that it's in picture but I can't post it in code type. Also I'm running on Window 10.

Comment: Try this instead of what you have now: `handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = HttpClientHandler.DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator;` As per [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclienthandler.dangerousacceptanyservercertificatevalidator), it could work.

Comment: Thanks. It work now.